# min-height of parent and position absolute of child

Tags: css

I have something like this:

```
.c1-pattern {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Because all parents of this `div` has `height: 100%`, it works fine and after resize window or on smaller resolutions, pattern cover not only window.height but all `div` after scroll down.

In this `.c1-pattern div` I want't to put `div` with `position: absolute` and `overflow: hidden`:

```
.c1-absolute {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And here is problem. It takes only window `height` - not `min-height`. So when I watch site on smaller devices, `.c1-pattern` works ok but `.c1-absolute` doesn't and end on `window.height`.

Is some way to make it work?

ANSWER:

.c1-patter{position:relative;}

and all works for now.

Comment: You need to change `top: 0,` and `bottom: 0,` to `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;`.

Comment: it was bug in here not in script

Comment: Can you show your complete HTML / CSS? If `.c1-absolute` is a child of `.c1-pattern`, and it should position itself in relation to it, then `.c1-pattern` should have `position: relative`.

Comment: Yes, exackly I just made it few seconds ago :)) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/5xsbnn3y/

Try changing height `min-height: 100vh;` which will take the height of the window inspite of div having height `200%`

```css
html,
body,
.cont {
  height: 200%;
}
.cont {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 200%;
}
.c1-pattern {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: Red;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="c1-pattern">
    <p>Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ok I get it - I think ... i set position:relative to .c1-pattern and now it seems to work.